# Count only active items for all categories in Codeigniter 3

Tags: select, join, count, codeigniter-3

In Codeignitor3.1.6, I have two tables- categories and items. And I want to list all categories with counts of items (active ='1' only) for each categories. For example, I have 6 categories and want to show all of them even their count is zero as below:

- Category 1 (5)
- category 2 (13)
- category 3 (0)
- category 4 (30)
- category 5 (0)
- category 6 (3)

Here is my model:

```
public function count_items()
{
    $q = $this->db->select('categories.name, COUNT(items.id) as xx')
    ->from('categories')
    ->join('items', 'categories.id = items.category_id', 'left')
    ->group_by('categories.name')->get();

    return $q;
}
```

I want to count only items.active ='1', but if I use ->where('items.active','1'), the list misses category 3 and category 5.
Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: you also need to test for when items.active is null  (See answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of a play with this.

The reason you are seeing those results is due to the case where there are no entries for a non existing item for the category and therefore testing for items.active = 1 results in a NULL.

So I added in a where that deals with that i.e `or_where('items.active',NULL)`

I created a new function ( for testing along with the original ) and adding this extra command works a treat...

So your function becomes...

```
// Original count_items() with added or_where() 
public function count_items_active()
{
    $q = $this->db->select('categories.name, COUNT(items.id) as xx')
        ->from('categories')
        ->join('items', 'categories.id = items.category_id', 'left')
        ->where('items.active',1)
        ->or_where('items.active',NULL)
        ->group_by('categories.name')
        ->get();
    return $q;
}
```